# Mongoid::Document label localization

Tags: ruby-on-rails, localization, mongoid

How do I localize form labels for Mongoid::Document objects?

For ActiveRecord and ActiveModel, I put these in my somelang.yml:

```
activerecord:
  attributes:
    user:
      name: "Foo"
activemodel:
  attributes:
    user:
      name: "Bar"
```

For Mongoid and localization I only find information about localizing attribute content, not attribute names (label).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works for me:

```
mongoid:
  attributes:
    user:
      name: "Nombre Schmombre"
```